# Why is tr replacing a character three times?

Tags: zsh, tr

I am running a command from the terminal. I am using zsh as my shell. My goal is to replace all instances of `’` with `'` within all txt files in this directory and all subdirectories.

I have a file with the following text:

> This is a test: ’

When I run the following command

`for file in *.txt(.); tr \’ \' < $file | sponge $file`

the file ends up like this

> This is a test: '''

The replacement works, but it happens three times. This does not seem to be an issue with sponge but happens however tr is used.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, but I suspect that your version of `tr` does not support multi-byte characters (`’` is represented with three bytes in UTF-8). There's some more info here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/228570/432774

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about `tr`, but you can just use native [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh) for this:

```sh
for file in *.txt(.); do
  { > $file } <<< ${"$( < $file )"//’/\'}
done
```

References:

- https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Redirection.html
- https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html